# Kubernetes on Windows Error: Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp some ip

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes

I have downloaded Docker and then enabled Kubernetes on the Desktop. When I execute 'Kubectl version' command on the PowerShell it says:

kubectl : Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp : connectex:
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has
failed to respond.
At line:1 char:1

- kubectl version

Answer (score 2):

The same issue I've had encountered just today and I found the solution the same day.

Here's the solution to my problem:

1. I pressed right-click on my Docker icon at the taskbar.
2. I changed the cluster that my k8s is pointing at from the 'gke_regal-hybrid' to 'docker-desktop' (in your case, must be different) and I was able to rerun the commands without any problems anymore.

[image: Click this for image reference]

Comment: Nice. Mine was pointing to `rancher-desktop`, which I hadn't started. I switched it to `docker-desktop` and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue started to occur today when I run anything related to kubectl on Windows. However, it previously worked fine. Maybe there are some recent updates in Windows/Docker.

**UPD**

Actually, my network sharing options were reset for some reasons. Please try the solution described below (works for me)

***SOLUTION:***

Check your Network and Sharing settings:

*Control Panel > Network and Sharing > [YOUR_NETWORK] (For me it's my Wi-Fi connection) > Properties > Sharing*

On the **Sharing** tab make sure that you have all checkboxes checked and that you selected the correct virtual network in the "Home network connection" field. If not, please use the correct one.

Comment: I could not find these Network and Sharing settings on Windows 10 OS. Which OS you are referring to here?

Comment: I use Windows 10 Pro 19042.1165.
You also can reach the same window by right clicking you network icon in the tray > Open Network & Internet Settings. Network and Sharing Center could be found there in the Advanced network setting section