# Why kubectl is unable to connect to server via: kubectl apply -f k8s/canary/namespace.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

So I was going to set up a GKE cluster and interact it with `kubectl`. But when I tried to apply the namespace, it just threw an error.

I've added my IP to Control plane authorized networks in GKE dashboard.

I'm using a Windows 10 machine, my kube/config

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: [REDACTED]
    server: https://34.66.200.196
  name: gke_project-307907_us-central1_test
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: gke_project-307907_us-central1_test
    user: gke_project-307907_us-central1_test
  name: gke_project-307907_us-central1_test
current-context: gke_project-307907_us-central1_test
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: gke_project-307907_us-central1_test
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      command: gke-gcloud-auth-plugin.exe
      installHint: Install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin for use with kubectl by following
        https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke
      provideClusterInfo: true
```

I tried to apply namespace but,

```bash
╰─ kubectl apply -f k8s/canary/namespace.yaml
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 34.66.200.196:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Comment: Seems unable to reach the cluster - may be a connectivity problem from your local machine to the cluster. Did you try running a simple `kubectl cluster-info` cmd to see if you're getting a response?

Comment: ╰─ kubectl cluster-info: 

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 34.66.200.196:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: Certainly seems a connectivity problem. Try running the cmd suggested `kubectl cluster-info dump`.
It could be that there is no network connectivity in the first place or there is something wrong with your kubeconfig file.

Comment: ╰─ kubectl cluster-info dump
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 34.66.200.196:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
**It's same as before.**

Comment: Try checking your outbound connectivity, inbound firewall configuration on the cluster, the kubeconfig file for any manual misconfigurations, the certificate being used etc

Comment: Hello @ImRopoxPro, Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know the answer below helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Comment: Hello, tried all the solutions you gave, it fixed the previous error, but now it gives another one:
"Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [IP AND PORT]: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

Comment: If the connecting source machine is not within this IP range, then it throws the timeout error while executing kubectl command. Edit the authorized networks CIDR range to allow the respective IP. Refer to the following [Add an authorized network to an existing cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/authorized-networks#add).

Comment: If still error is there, verify if the source machine does have External IP, if there is no external IP attached to the machine, the traffic is being routed through the NAT gateway or a proxy setup which provides internet connection to the machine. You need to add the respective IP to the authorized networks to resolve the issue.

Comment: If the Private Cluster has also the shared VPC enabled, you have to add the IP address of the Cloud NAT gateway which is present in the host project into the authorized networks of the cluster.

You can find this address by using GA to access into the host project of the Shared VPC network. Search for IP Addresses in the VPC network and then try to find the NAT gateway IP address that is currently in use by the router which routes the requests for the Network traffic in the perticular VPC.  Adding this IP address to the Authorized networks in the cluster may resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Looks kubectl lost connection to the Cluster and you can set the Cluster context by following the official GCP troubleshooting doc [GCP kubectl command times out](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#kubectl-times-out), try below two solutions :**
**Solutions 1 : When kubectl cannot communicate with the cluster control plane or doesn't exist:**

> To resolve your issue, verify the context were the cluster is set:
>
> Go to `$HOME/.kube/config` or run the command `kubectl config view` to
> verify the config file contains the cluster context and the external
> IP address of the control plane (Check there is a possibility that the
> server mentioned was old or not reachable).
>
> Set the cluster credentials:
>
> ```
>     gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME \
>             --region=COMPUTE_REGION \
>             --project=PROJECT_ID
> ```
>
> **Note :** For zonal clusters, use `--zone=COMPUTE_ZONE`

Above command will automatically update the default cluster for kubectl. In case you don’t know the correct cluster name and zone, use `gcloud container clusters list`. After completing the above steps, please try to create the namespace again and let me know the outcome.

**Solution 2 : Source IP is not allowed on the "`Control plane authorized networks`" - cluster config :**

> If the cluster is a private GKE cluster, then ensure that the outgoing
> IP of the machine you are attempting to connect from is included in
> the list of existing authorized networks.
>
> You can find your existing authorized networks by running the
> following command:
>
> ```
>   gcloud container clusters describe  \
>     --region= --project= \
>     --format "flattened(masterAuthorizedNetworksConfig.cidrBlocks[])"
> ```

In GKE, there is a feature called "`Control plane authorized networks`". The main purpose of this parameter is to allow the user to specify CIDR ranges and allow IP addresses in those ranges to [access GKE cluster endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/private-cluster-concept#overview).

You can also use the GCP console to check the allowed IP CIDR in the "`Control plane authorized networks`" from the GKE cluster details.

**Other Scenarios :**

**a.** For other common reasons refer to **Uli Köhler’s** blog on **Techover flow** [How to fix kubectl Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp …:443: i/o timeout](https://techoverflow.net/2019/04/01/how-to-fix-kubectl-unable-to-connect-to-the-server-dial-tcp-443-i-o-timeout/).

**b.** Check If you're using docker's default bridge network as your GKE endpoint, disable the bridge network to avoid the network conflict.

**c.** Also, check if there are recent updates in **Windows/Docker**. Refer to **Dzmitry Paulouski’s** answer [Kubernetes on Windows Error: Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68954948/kubernetes-on-windows-error-unable-to-connect-to-the-server-dial-tcp-some-ip), which may help to resolve your issue.

**d.** If the issue with the config file, restarts the Docker Desktop restores with the new config file by adding/replacing it in your `HOME/.kube / config file`.